# How to associate some value in model with ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models: **Product** and **Currency**.

```
class Product(models.Model):
  Currency = models.ManyToManyField(
    'Currency', verbose_name=u'Currency', blank=True, null=True)

class Currency(models.Model):
  Name = models.CharField(u'Currency Name', max_lenght=16)
  Sign = models.CharField(u'Currency Sign', max_lenght=4)
```

What is the best way to associate some value from models.Product to models.Currency?
Example:
The model.Currency contains objects 'USD', 'Euro', 'Krona'.
The model.Product contains an object 'Cactus' which associated with models.Currency 'USD' and 'Euro'.
How can I set some value (price) to 'USD' and 'Euro'?
I whant something like this:

```
Product.objects.get(Name='Cactus').get_price(Current.objects.get(Name='USD'))
Product.objects.get(Name='Cactus').get_price(Current.objects.get(Name='Euro'))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    currencies = models.ManyToManyField('Currency', through='Pricing', blank=True, null=True)

class Currency(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    sign = models.CharField()

class Pricing(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

and then you can use something like

```
product = Product.objects.get(name='Cactus')
price = product.pricing_set.get(currency__name='USD')
```

Comment: Excellent! So much time to read the documentation and did not notice this option :) Thanks!